# ol3 error with style function -- feature shows half geometry

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector, style

I used `stylelayerfunction` with unique colors for all the different 700 points. While applying it some features are rendered correctly and some features are half render.

While using single style it rendered perfect.

in `stylelayerfunction` i just set the different color.

The feature geometry in both the cases are same.

I can not understand why it is happen.

Comment: please add some screenshots to show us what is happening and some code to show how you are applying the style function.